# Init message from the bot in aiml

Tags: chatbot, aiml

I'm programming a bot in aiml using programAB and I wonder if there is anyway to make the bot start the conversation,like 'Hello, how are you?', not just waiting for the human to say anything.

Comment: You won't be able to do this in pure AIML and will need to look at your interface. I get mine to send a message to the bot when the interface loads which calls a category called XINTRODUCTION. This has a template of "Hi. How can I help you?"

The user doesn't have to type XINTRODUCTION and so it looks like the bot has spoken first.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much Steve, I'll look inside all the java files to try to do that :)

Answer (score -1):

You can send a message to the bot first in the code then take the answer of the bot show it and start the chat.